# NG-Model check if same data is already entered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form that looks like this

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form form--login">
                        <div class="form__field">
                          <label class="fontawesome-user" for="login__firstname"><span class="hidden">Name</span></label>
                          <input id="login__firstname" ng-model="emailInvite.forename" typ

e="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__field">
                          <label class="fontawesome-user" for="login__surname"><span class="hidden">Surname</span></label>
                          <input id="login__surname" ng-model="emailInvite.surname" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Surname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form__field">
                          <label class="fontawesome-envelope" for="login__email"><span class="hidden">Email</span></label>
                          <input id="login__email" ng-model="emailInvite.email" type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <p>Upload Emails here </p>
                         <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                         <p class="help-block">Using .csv to upload</p>
                       </div>
                        <div class="form__field">
                          <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="saveInvites()" value="Save Email">
                        </div>
                      </form>
```

Currently it populates a database and a list, I'm wanting to make it so that the list doesn't populate is the same detials are entered twice. e.g. same email.

Heres my controller for the form

```
$scope.emailInvite = {
  forename: '',
  surname: '',
  email: ''
};

$scope.saveInvites = function (){
  var emailDetails = {
    forename: $scope.emailInvite.forename,
    surname: $scope.emailInvite.surname,
    email: $scope.emailInvite.email,
    event_id: $scope.eventId
  }

  $scope.emailInvites.push(emailDetails);

  var res = $http.post('/delegates.json', emailDetails);

  res.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // $state.go('event.payments');
      bootbox.alert("Saved email details");
  });
  res.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      //TODO proper error needs fixes on server
      bootbox.alert("Email not saved: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
  });
};
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to check for duplicates on the client or on the server? For this to be checked on the client side, you will need to have the data available on the client, or do an AJAX request on submit. Otherwise it is a server side solution where you check for duplicates and not save if it already exists.

Comment: The NG-Model has it stored.

Comment: `ng-model` only has the current value. It doesn't know what values are stored in your database. Every time someone enters a new value, you need to either (a.) make a request to the server to check if it already exists and alert the user or (b.) pass the data and on the server side reject/ignore the value if it already exists